# Using a for loop to assign values

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, variable-assignment

Is there a way in R to use for loop to create new columns in the existing data frame and assign the values to the newly created columns?

```
s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM['CM_2018001'] = s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$AFE_Cost_2018001/s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$Dr_2018001
   s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM['CM_2018002'] = s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$AFE_Cost_2018002/s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$Dr_2018001
   s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM['CM_2018003'] = s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$AFE_Cost_2018003/s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$Dr_2018001
   s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM['CM_2018004'] = s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$AFE_Cost_2018004/s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$Dr_2018001
   s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM['CM_2018005'] = s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$AFE_Cost_2018005/s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$Dr_2018001
   s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM['CM_2018006'] = s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$AFE_Cost_2018006/s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$Dr_2018001
   s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM['CM_2018007'] = s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$AFE_Cost_2018007/s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$Dr_2018001
   s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM['CM_2018008'] = s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$AFE_Cost_2018008/s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$Dr_2018001
   s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM['CM_2018009'] = s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$AFE_Cost_2018009/s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$Dr_2018001
   s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM['CM_2018010'] = s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$AFE_Cost_2018010/s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$Dr_2018001
   s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM['CM_2018011'] = s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$AFE_Cost_2018011/s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$Dr_2018001
   s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM['CM_2018012'] = s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$AFE_Cost_2018012/s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$Dr_2018001
```

Can this be written in 1 line using some loop? Please note that we are assigning to the values by creating new columns. I tried using assing() function but it R is creating new variables outside the data frame instead of adding it in the same data frame

Comment: what kind of data structure is this? is it stored in a list? Or do the column names just have strange variable names?

Comment: that is a data frame .. s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM is the name of my data frame.

Comment: If the idea here is you want a "CM" calculated as the ratio of AFE_Cost / Dr[in 2018001], it would be more typical in R to keep CM in one column, with a row per time period, based on AFE_Cost for that time period. Then the calculation would be very straightforward. Then, if necessary, you could reshape that output into whatever columns you want.   If you want more specific assistance, please review the guidelines for how ask a question on this forum, and share example data in the same format as what you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. Simply assign multiple columns with `paste0` along a sequence of numbers:

```
s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM[paste0("CM_", 2018001:2018012)] <- s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM[paste0("AFE_Cost_", 2018001:2018012)]/s_0133_AFE_Nr_Dr_CM$Dr_2018001
```